# How to detect tomcat context reload

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications

I have a config.properties file to store Credentials and IP address for my application as Key Value pairs. However writes to this properties file reloads the application context in tomcat.
I am writing to properties file as below

```
   URL propUrl=this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(PROPERTIES_FILE);
   prop.store(new FileOutputStream(propUrl.getPath()), null);
```

So,

1.) Is there a way to detect a tomcat context reload in Java.

or

2.) Is there a way to prevent context reload and read the config.properties file

Comment: Perhaps you could use a ServletContextListener: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html - That's how we detect that our servlet context is initialized and destroyed.  Not sure how/if it works with _re-loads_.

Answer (score 1):

1. If the ServletContextListener is not helping. You can try using a LifeCycleListener
2. Set the property `reloadable=false` to prevent reloading of the context.

Answer (score 0):

To disable automatic reloading of the context (which is the Tomcat term for the webapp), set the `reloadable` attribute of the `<Context>` element in the server config to `false`. [See here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html) for reference, search for "reloadable".